# Script: How do I add numeric CPU id to the name of each syscall to show which core it is executing on?

Tags: system-calls

This is .stp file. How do I add numeric CPU id to the name of each syscall to show which core it is executing on?

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap

global activity           // [execname,tid]->syscall-count
global activity2          // [execname,tid]->syscall-name-string-history

global syscall_history_length = 50 // override with stap -Gsyscall_history_length=NNN
global top_threads = 20

probe nd_syscall.* # use non-dwarf variant; we don't need context data
{
  activity[execname(),tid()]<<<1
  history = name." ".activity2[execname(),tid()]
  activity2[execname(),tid()] = substr(history,0,syscall_history_length)
}

probe timer.s(5) 
{
  printf("%16s %6s %5s %-*s\n\n", "execname", "tid", "count", 
                           syscall_history_length, "recent syscalls");
  foreach ([e,t] in activity- limit top_threads) 
  {
    printf("%16s %6d %5d %s", e, t, @count(activity[e,t]), activity2[e,t])
    printf("\n")
  }    
  printf("\n")
  delete activity
 delete activity2
```

}